How to write shell scripts to install Kitsune Mask and LsPosed on Android emulator?
I need update and install Kitsune Mask (Magisk) and LsPosed on several android emulator very often. Meantime I have to reboot emulators 2 or 3 times during the installations. Is it possible to write some kind of shell scripts to make the whole process automatically?
THANK YOU!

A shell script is a bunch of commands. For your use case, manually type the commands on the cmd-line then make a file, and copy/paste the manual cmds into the file. Add #!/bin/bash as the very first line to the file. Save the file like myInstallerScript. Now make it executable with chmod +x myInstallerScript, and run it with ./myInstallerScript. After that if you still need help, then post a new question, include the exact text of error messages and read the section How to turn a bad script into a good question . Good luck.

First, thank you for your reply. It's not difficult to write and execute scripts. What I want know is how to install Kitsune Mask (Magisk) and LsPosed by scripts.  To be precise, I want to know what files are needed and where should I copy them to for the case.

That's not how I intepreted " Is it possible to write some kind of shell scripts to make the whole process automatically?" (-; . I have no idea about location of those files and as no android follower has made a comment, I suggest you delete here and repost to [android.se] , but only IMHO .  Good luck

As far as " Meantime I have to reboot emulators 2 or 3 times ..." , I would define a series of flag files stored in a special directory that doesn't get erased on reboot (I don't think you can rely on stuff saved to /tmp). You test for the non-existence of the flag files in process order (step1, 2, 3 ...), and when you don't have a flag file, you do that step and continue, only creating that step's flag file when it has completed successfully. Of course you have to reset when you want to start testing anew . Good luck.
